# python metaclass pass __init__ params

Tags: python, init, metaclass

I'm learning metaclass programming in python 3, but I have some problems

```
class UpperAttrMetaClass(type): # to uppercase all attrs
    def __new__(mcs, class_name, class_parents, class_attr):
        attrs = ((name, value) for name, value in class_attr.items() if not 
            name.startswith('__'))
        uppercase_attrs = dict((name.upper(), value) for name, value in attrs)
        return super(UpperAttrMetaClass, mcs).__new__(mcs, class_name, 
                     class_parents, uppercase_attrs)

class Base(metaclass=UpperAttrMetaClass):
    bar = 12
    def __init__(self, params):
        super(Base, self).__init__()
        self.params = params

t = Base(1)
print(t.BAR)
print(t.params)
```

This code can uppercase all attrs.

I want to pass a parameter to **init**, but when I run this code, I'm prompted to make a mistake that

```
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You remove the `__init__` method altogether when uppercasing.

Comment: Deleting `__init__` doesn't make a difference, you get the error either way.

Comment: why can't use __init__ in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering out the `__init__` method:

```
attrs = ((name, value) for name, value in class_attr.items() if not 
    name.startswith('__'))
```

`attrs` are all the attributes that do not start with `__`. You then uppercase those `attrs` and use those for the class you create, so `__init__` is *never used for the new class*. Because the resulting `Bar` class has no `__init__` method, `object.__init__` is used, and that method doesn't take parameters:

```
>>> sorted(vars(Base))
['BAR', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__module__', '__weakref__']
>>> Base.__init__
<slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>
```

Include **all** attributes, do not filter, but only uppercase those without `__`:

```
class UpperAttrMetaClass(type): # to uppercase all attrs
    def __new__(mcs, class_name, class_parents, class_attr):
        attrs = {name if name.startswith('__') else name.upper(): value for name, value in class_attr.items()}
        return super().__new__(mcs, class_name, class_parents, attrs)
```

I used a dictionary comprehension here; note the `name if name.startswith('__') else name.upper()` conditional expression, which produces an uppercase attribute name when the name does not start with `__`.

I also used the 0-argument form of `super()`, this is Python 3 after all.

Now the metaclass works correctly and `Base.__init__` exists:

```
>>> sorted(vars(Base))
['BAR', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', '__weakref__']
>>> t = Base(1)
>>> t.BAR
12
>>> t.params
1
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized my mistake!